# Spring Multi Action Controller

Tags: xml, spring, controller

I am trying to get a multi action controller working so I can use it for navigation purposes, I have one working already which handles json and they are in the same config file and the json mappings work and the correct method gets called.

For some reason my second controller (defined first in the xml file) doesnt work, I get a 404 with a no mapping for url in the log file. It is probably something simple that I have missed but I just cant see what. Appreciate any help!

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

<bean name="navigationController" class="NavigationController">
    <property name="methodNameResolver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.PropertiesMethodNameResolver">
            <property name="mappings">
                <props>
                   <prop key="/dashboard">dashBoard</prop>
                </props>
           </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

public ModelAndView dashBoard(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("hitting the avigation controller now - loading the dashboard");

    return new ModelAndView("dashboard", "msg","Testing the model and view");
}
```

This entry in the same config file works and all methods are called appropriately:

```
<bean name="chartController" class="ChartController">
    <property name="methodNameResolver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.PropertiesMethodNameResolver">
            <property name="mappings">
                <props>
                   <prop key="/chart/barChart">barChart</prop>
                   <prop key="/chart/json">handleChartJsonRPC</prop>
                </props>
           </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: can you post the error log you are getting?

Comment: Hi, this the entry in the log file: 17-Jun-2013 12:04:14 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/nhsia/results/dashboard] in DispatcherServlet with name 'results-controller'

Comment: is `nhsia` the context path?

Comment: Try changing `<prop key="/dashboard">dashBoard</prop>` to `<prop key="/results/dashboard">dashBoard</prop>`

Comment: yes nhsia is the context, I will try what you suggested.

Comment: Ok that didnt seem to make any difference, I will add the entry that works, but I dont see any difference between this and the navigation controller mappings.

Comment: It may also have to do with `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping`, it expects the controller to be mapped to a url like `/navigation/dashboard`

Comment: Excellent thanks. That works, simply prepending /navigation to my url makes it work. Does ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping expect the name of the controller to be the first part of the url?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may also have to do with `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping`, it expects the controller to be mapped to a url like `/navigation/dashboard`